# WinSCP + QProcess. Проблема вызова скрипта

Tags: c++, qt, winscp

Возникает странная проблема:
Создаю процесс для использования WinSCP. При этом предварительно создаю скрипт `tmpWinScpScript`. Файл `tmpWinScpScript`создается в Temp папке юзера и потенциально путь его может содержать пробелы, поэтому имя файла в скрипте я обрамляю кавычками. Такое использование winSCP поддерживает.

```
    QProcess process;
    process.start(ui->leWinScp->text(), QStringList()<<"/ini=nul"<<"/script=\""+tmpWinScpScript+"\"");

    if (!process.waitForStarted()){
        return false;
    }

    do {
        QString tmpStr = process.readAllStandardOutput();
        if (!tmpStr.isEmpty())
            ui->teLog->appendHtml(tmpStr);
        qApp->processEvents();
    } while (!process.waitForFinished(10));

    qDebug()<<process.exitCode();
```

Однако при вызове этого кода получаю следующий ответ: `Cannot open file "E:\C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\script.tmp\". Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома`. При этом команда вызываемая в process выглядит как `C:/Program Files (x86)/WinSCP/WinSCP.com /ini=nul /script="C:/Users/Roman/AppData/Local/Temp/script.tmp"`. Т.е. кто-то пока не знаю кто добавляет `E:\` к моему пути. Что вообще происходит? Выполнение команды описанной выше в командной строки приводит к желаемому результату.

Comment: скорей всего лишние кавычки после `script=`, а ещё `WinSCP` может ожидать обратные слеши в пути...

Comment: Я всё перепррбовал. Прямые, обратные слэши, кавычки. Из командной строки все норм, а из QProcess вылетает эта странная ошибка, когда использую кавычки. Более этого, есть способ вызова QProcess, когда ты все аргументы передаешь одной строкой и там вариант с кавычками работает. Вопрос только в том - это баг и надо создавать тикет в Qt или я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: кавычки должны интерпретироваться оболочкой, так что они здесь почти наверняка лишние... про то, в каком формате должен быть путь я не уверен, но всё же стоит попробовать прогнать его через `QDir::toNativeSeparators()`...